# Setting up Google Geomap visualization for Italy regions

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, geomap

I'm trying to set up a geomap visualization for Italy's regions, but if I use regions, instead of markers for my dataMode option it doesn't work. I'm obviously just beginning to learn how to use this API, thank you in advance.

```
function drawVisualization() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addRows(2);
      data.addColumn('string', 'Region');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Popularity');
      data.setValue(0, 0, 'Tuscany');
      data.setValue(0, 1, 200);
      data.setValue(1, 0, 'Verona');
      data.setValue(1, 1, 300);

      var options = {};
      options['region'] = 'IT';
      options['colors'] = [0xFF0000, 0xc06000];
      options['dataMode'] = 'markers';

      var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(
          document.getElementById('visualization'));
      geomap.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps set up an example on http://jsfiddle.net for us to have a look at.

Comment: I was not using appropriate region names. For example when using 'Tuscany', what I intended was 'Toscana', or even 'IT-52' would work.

Comment: ok.  Perhaps you should answer your own question here or even delete it if you don't think it's useful for others.

Comment: I'll answer it tomorrow, I tried already, but I guess I have to wait 24 hours.

Comment: Oh ok.  I didn't know there was that rule.

Answer (score 1):

```
function drawMap() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addRows(6);
    data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Popularity');
    data.setValue(0, 0, 'Lombardia');
    data.setValue(0, 1, 200);
    data.setValue(1, 0, 'Campania');
    data.setValue(1, 1, 300);
    data.setValue(2, 0, 'Lazio');
    data.setValue(2, 1, 400);
    data.setValue(3, 0, 'Toscana');
    data.setValue(3, 1, 500);
    data.setValue(4, 0, 'Sicilia');
    data.setValue(4, 1, 600);
    data.setValue(5, 0, 'Veneto');
    data.setValue(5, 1, 700);

    var options = {};
    options['dataMode'] = 'regions';
    options['region'] = 'IT';
    var container = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(container);
    geomap.draw(data, options);
};
```